# Unable to start Django server inside docker container

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am unable to connect to the Django server on a docker container. I am trying to use 0.0.0.0:8000 to connect and I used "docker-compose up" to create a container.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./PriceAlertWeb
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: serverimg3
    container_name: servercon3
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /ServerCode/
COPY . /ServerCode/
RUN pip install -r req.txt
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I am able to create a container successfully. But when I try accessing it with "http://127.0.0.1:8000/userDetails/", I'm unable to see my content.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please note that when I try running "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" on my local, my application functions as expected. (Screenshots below)

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
Docker logs
[image]

Comment: Could you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: I have posted it, please check :) @Shinratensei

Comment: It should be the same, but can you confirm `localhost:8000` is also inaccessible?

Comment: Yes. localhost is inaccessible too @yedpodtrzitko

Comment: can you please check the logs of the container?

Comment: Added container logs to the question @AashayAmballi

Comment: can you check `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in your settings...  make sure it should be `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it, but it still didn't work. @ShivendraPratapKushwaha

Comment: It's kinda weird... One suggestion that I don't know if will fix this but should be added regardless: your ports in the compose file should be a string: `"8000:8000"`

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I tried changing to "8000:8000". Unfortunately, the problem still persists. @Shinratensei

Comment: Hey @CharithaReddy can you add an environment variable to your Dockerfile ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 and try rebuilding the container by running docker-compose up -d --build. Also can you remove the CMD from your dockerfile and try adding - command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 in the docker-compose.yml

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @AashayAmballi. I tried the changes you said and I still see the same issue. I see that the container logs haven't changed either and they are the same as in the one that I posted.

Comment: So the runserver is running inside the container right? did you check that?

Comment: I believe it is. In one of the screenshots I posted, I executed "docker ps" and I got the container running with the command "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" @AashayAmballi

Comment: Okay, after adding pythonunbuffered in dockerfile, can you show what it's logging when you check the container logs? Is it showing similar to what it is showing when you run the runserver locally

Comment: It says "Watching for file changes with StatReloader".The same logs what I posted in my question- @AashayAmballi

Comment: In your docker file add `EXPOSE 8000`